# php curl login to a flash form possible?

Tags: php, curl

Is is possible to login to a form thats created with flash? If so could someone show me an example to this login `https://www.siriusxm.com/player/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login happends in the server side.
Meaning: you need a script that sends the credencials to the server side: in this case
https://www.siriusxm.com/userservices/authentication/en-us/xml/user/login
You have some work to do in order to reverse engineer the proccess.

BTW, the flash sends the credencials like that:

```
<authenticationRequest><login>THE_USERNAME</login><consumerType>ump</consumerType><currency>840</currency><password>THE_PAWWEORD</password><subscriberType></subscriberType></authenticationRequest>
```

That is from analyzing the AJAX request via the browser.

Comment: hmm this seems a little more difficult than i thought. what do you men by reverse engineer exactly. sorry still new to php :p

Comment: This is not so simple to "Hack" a login form, you have to understand the information protocol and try to relive the session on each request.
If you are new to PHP most likely it is not a good idea to deal with it... this one requires more skills...